# DateTime month 0 invalid format

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, datetime

I'm having strange behavior of DateTime in c#.

I'm trying to initialize a datepicker in January. So I make a new date:

```
DateTime MyDate = new DateTime(2017, 0, 15);
```

But I get this exception:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.

If I use `(2017, 1, 15)` it works but the time dialog, initialized with:

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
    Activity,
    this,
    MyDate.Year,
    MyDate.Month,
    MyDate.Day);
```

Goes on February.

Well I tried to "cheat" and did:

```
DateTime MyDate = new DateTime(2017, 1, 15);
DateTime = DateTime.AddMonths(-1);
```

No error, but the date picker goes on February.

The only way to have January is:

```
DateTime MyDate = new DateTime(2017, 12, 15);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1 is January there is no 0... its not like index

Comment: don't confused with array index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *issue* is how the [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx) object treats month values (1-12) and how the [`DatePickerDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) treats month values (0-11).

---

`DateTime` constructor:

> strange behavior of DateTime
>
> ```
> DateTime MyDate = new DateTime(2017, 0, 15);
> ```

If we take a look at the `DateTime` [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx), it is clearly stated that the month value should be *1 through 12*, which is not valid in your case and hence the exception. We can correct it as below:

```
DateTime MyDate = new DateTime(2017, 1, 15);
```

---

`DatePickerDialog` constructor:

Exception (or strange behavior) will arise when we try - `new DatePickerDialog` in combination with the month value of `DateTime` as the constructor of `DatePickerDialog` is expecting the month values from *0-11*.

It is stated that [`int: the initially selected month (0-11 for compatibility with MONTH)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#DatePickerDialog(android.content.Context,%20android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,%20int,%20int,%20int))

The approach which can then be followed is to give the correct `index` for month to `DatePickerDialog` constructor as below:

```
DateTime MyDate = new DateTime(2017, 1, 15);
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity,
                                               this,
                                               MyDate.Year,
                                               MyDate.Month - 1,
                                               MyDate.Day);
```

Comment: Note that in javascript native dates, the month is zero-indexed. the cause of a lot of confusion ...

Answer (score 9):

[`DateTime.Month`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month(v=vs.110).aspx) is a value between 1 and 12, which aligns with what most people think a month 'number' is.

Per the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html), the`DatePickerDialog` constructor you are calling accepts a zero-based month. It accepts values in the range 0-11, so you need to subtract one from the `DateTime.Month`.

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity,
    this, MyDate.Year, MyDate.Month - 1, MyDate.Day);
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful!